# A single expression for guard case let with type casting of the associated type?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following enum:

```
enum JSONData {
    case dict([String:Any])
    case array([Any])
}
```

I would like to do a pattern matching assignment *with type casting* using guard case let.  I not only want to make sure that `someData` is `.array`, but that its associated type is `[Int]` and not just `[Any]`. Is this possible with a single expression? Something like the following:

```
let someData: JSONData = someJSONData()
guard case let .array(anArray as [Int]) = someData
else { return }
```

But the above does not compile; the error is `downcast pattern value of type '[Int]' cannot be used`. I know this is possible with the following but I'd rather do it in a single expression if possible.

```
guard case let .array(_anArray) = someData, let anArray = _anArray as? [Int]
else { return }
```

Edit on April 27, 2018: An update to this situation: you may now use the following syntax as long as the cast type is not a `Collection`:

```
enum JSONData {
    case dict([String:Any])
    case array(Any)  // Any, not [Any]
}

func f() {
    let intArray: JSONData = .array(1)
    guard case .array(let a as Int) = intArray else {
        return
    }
    print("a is \(a)")
}

f()  // "a is 1"
```

If you attempt to use a collection type such as `[Int]`, you receive the error `error: collection downcast in cast pattern is not implemented; use an explicit downcast to '[Int]' instead`.

Comment: I want to say `case .array(let x as [Int])` but I'm not near a computer!

Comment: Nope, same error

Comment: If it's a switch statement, I think you can use a where clause `case .array(let x) where x is [Int]`, possibly in guard as well.

Comment: If I apply that to the `guard case let`, then `x` does not get type `[Int]`. The correct logic is used to determine whether the guard passes, but afterward `x` will still have type `[Any]`.

Comment: One last try until I have to go home and get my computer, `case .array(let x) as .array([Int])`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible due to a limitation in Swift's pattern matching implementation. It's actually called out [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/Parse/matching_patterns.swift#L291):

> // FIXME: We don't currently allow subpatterns for "isa" patterns that
>   // require interesting conditional downcasts.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358828/5099014) attempts to explain why, though falls short. However, they do point to an interesting piece of information that makes the things work if you don't use a generic as the associated value.

The following code achieves the one-liner, but loses some other functionality:

```
enum JSONData {
    case dict(Any)
    case array(Any)
}

let someData: JSONData = JSONData.array([1])

func test() {
    guard case .array(let anArray as [Int]) = someData else {
        return
    }

    print(anArray)
}
```

Alternatively, the same one liner can be achieved through a utility function in the enum definition that casts the underlying value to `Any`. This route preserves the nice relationship between the cases and the types of their associated values.

```
enum JSONData {
    case dict([String : Any])
    case array(Array<Any>)

    func value() -> Any {
        switch self {
        case .dict(let x):
            return x
        case .array(let x):
            return x
        }
    }
}

// This coercion only works if the case is .array with a type of Int
guard let array = someData.value() as? [Int] else {
    return false
}
```