# Switch on type contained in Array

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'd like to extract the type from an array passed as a parameter to a function, as to have the type parameter optional.

```
init(type: ContentType? = nil, style: LayoutStyle, content: [ContentProtocol]) {
    self.type = type ?? {
        switch content {
        case is [Ad]: return .ads
        case is [User]: return .users
        case is [List]: return .list
        default: fatalError("Can't assume.")
        }
    }()
}
```

`Ad`, `User` and `List` all conform to `ContentProtocol`.

These switch statements cause an error, `"Optional type '[Ad/User/List]' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead"` which is not what I want to do.

This init however, does work.

```
init(type: ContentType? = nil, style: LayoutStyle, fetcher: ContentFetcher) {
    self.type = type ?? {
        switch fetcher {
        case is AdFetcher: return .ads
        case is UserFetcher: return .users
        case is ListFetcher: return .list
        default: fatalError("Can't assume.")
        }
    }()
}
```

`ContentFetcher` is another protocol, and all the types in the switch statement conforms to this.

Can I achieve the same as the last init with the first init?

Comment: Similar question (with possible workarounds): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355513/apple-swift-type-casting-generics, Swift bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5671

Comment: I have one question about your code, I was wondering why do you add the "type" argument to your init if its originally nil and if you always set its value depending on another argument from the very same init ("fetcher") ?

Comment: @Alex I'm just abusing optional parameters to have one init that I can call with an explicit type if I want to force it to be something else than what the init assumes normally. Also, it only sets the type to be assumed from the content parameter if you don't specify a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protocol P{}
struct A: P{}
struct B: P{}
struct C: P{}

let a = [A(), A()]
let b = [B(), B()]
let c = [C(), C()]

func foo(arr: [P]) {
    if let a = arr as? [A] {
        print(1, "A", a, type(of: a))
    } else if let b = arr as? [B] {
        print(1, "B", b, type(of: b))
    } else {
        print("not A nor B")
    }

    switch arr {
    case let a where a is [A]:
        print(2, "A", a, type(of: a))
    case let b where b is [B]:
        print(2, "B", b, type(of: b))
    default:
        print("not A nor B")
    }
    print()
}

foo(arr: a)
foo(arr: b)
foo(arr: c)
```

prints

```
1 A [__lldb_expr_245.A(), __lldb_expr_245.A()] Array<A>
2 A [__lldb_expr_245.A(), __lldb_expr_245.A()] Array<P>

1 B [__lldb_expr_245.B(), __lldb_expr_245.B()] Array<B>
2 B [__lldb_expr_245.B(), __lldb_expr_245.B()] Array<P>

not A nor B
not A nor B
```

if the input array is

```
let d:[P] = [A(), B()]
```

it prints

```
not A nor B
not A nor B
```

as expected